# Итератор по массиву

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Учу итераторы, и практикуюсь. Задача сделать итератор по массиву. Код правильный(вроде).
Но при создание с Integer, программа просит сменить обобщенный тип на int[] (T[] -> int[]). Хотя со String всё нормально.

Q73:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Q73<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private T[] array;
    private int index = 0;

    Q73(T[] array) { this.array = array; }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() { return index < array.length; }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if(!hasNext()) { throw new NoSuchElementException(); }
        return array[index++];
    }
}
```

Код в Main:

```
int[] arrayInt = new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,23,123,4,1,4,124,1};
        String[] arrayString = new String[]{"as","as","dsd","41","12"};

        Q73<String> Q = new Q73(arrayString);

        Q73<Iterator> Q2 = new Q73(arrayInt);
```

Ругается на Q73 Q2 = new Q73(**ARRAYINT**).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы вместо Integer передаёте Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Generics в Java - это полностью компиляция - компилятор превращает все общие применения в приведения в правильный тип. Это должно поддерживать обратную совместимость с предыдущими запусками JVM.

Это:

```
List<ClassA> list = new ArrayList<ClassA>();
list.add(new ClassA());
ClassA a = list.get(0);
```

превращается в (грубо):

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new ClassA());
ClassA a = (ClassA)list.get(0);
```

Итак, все, что используется как generics, должно быть преобразовано в Object (в этом примере get(0) возвращает Object), а примитивные типы - нет. Поэтому они не могут использоваться в дженериках.

Поэтому если вы хотите работать с примитивами, вы должны использовать их обертки:

- byte -> Byte
- int -> Integer
- short -> Short
- long -> Long
- float -> Float
- double -> Double
- boolean -> Boolean
- char -> Character

Например:

```
Integer [] ints;
```